# In C++, can the sum of two squared float be negative?

Tags: c++, floating-point, software-quality

I have a snippet of code that compute the sum of two squared `float`s:

```
float a, b, c;
// assign some random float to b and c
a = b*b+c*c;
```

Can `a`, the sum of the two squared `float`s, be negative?

The original snippet is inside a function, so a different way to put the question is the following:

```
bool fun(float b, float c)
{
   return b*b+c*c<0;
}
```

Is there any pair of values for `b` and `c` that gives `fun(b,c)==true`?

Comment: Can they be [`std::complex<float>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: Is negative 0 count?

Comment: `a >= 0` could also be `false` if any of the operands are `NaN`.

Comment: @Eljay no they can't.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson **NO**

Comment: As far as I am aware, no: Signs are multiplied independently so you get positive products anyway, which won't be changed by summing up. If the result doesn't fit into a float, you should then get positive infinity – not considering the NaN case!

Comment: @Jarod42 I am afraid I am not aware of negative zero :-(

Comment: If you write `b*b+c*c < 0` this always be `false`, but if you will write `b*b+c*c >= 0` this can be `false` even if mathematically it can't. It can happen if one of values is `NaN` and `NaN` compared to anything in any way is always `false`.

Comment: Note:  C++ does not *require* IEEE 754 behavior for `float` and `double`.  For many years, all my platforms have that behavior.  However... there may be modern platforms that do not use IEEE 754 rules, and certainly older platforms that did not abide by the IEEE 754 behavior.  For those platforms... you'll have to RTFM (read the fascinating manual).

Comment: NaN case: https://godbolt.org/z/j8d4a3jrP so define condition "negative" first.

Comment: You need to give your variables initial values, otherwise the random bit patterns could mean anything internally including a corrupt non-number with weird behaviour.

Comment: @Galik I phrased the question in a different way.

Comment: unless gcc is broken the answer is No https://godbolt.org/z/adxvTr655 ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Nice! I never remember the trick to ask the compiler!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: That demonstration only applies to the C implementation that GCC implements in that compilation. E.g., such an example does not show that its result holds in any C implementation, just in the one that GCC is compiling for, which likely includes some conformance to IEEE-754 et cetera.

Comment: @EricPostpischil right, the quesiton is not whether a standard conforming implementation must return `true` for some input, but whether returning `true` for some input is conforming.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible under IEEE754, as there is no wrap-around behaviour defined for `float` or `double`.

Let's assume that you are defining `a` to be negative if `a < 0.0` is `true`. That conveniently allows us to neglect NaN cases, assuming we continue to confine the analysis to IEEE754.

Under the above assumptions it's therefore not possible for the sum of two squares to be negative. Even if `a` is `-0.0` then `a * a` must be `0.0`. Furthermore, if `a` is `-inf` then `a * a` must be `+inf` (mathematicians are comfortable with that as the square of a countable infinity is also countable). The sum of two squares will be no less than either of the two squares comprising the sum.

---

**However**, note that formally the behaviour of floating point overflow is *undefined* by the C++ standard. We're fortunate that IEEE754 is ubiquitous and overflow is defined. It's possible that an implementation has a floating point scheme which does implement some sort of wraparound to negative.

To be on the safe side, test

```
std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559
```

Comment: Did you make a typo. "Positive" instead of "Negative"?

Comment: @AnoopRana: Let's publish jointly!

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Formally, the behavior is undefined, so yes wraparound *is* possible.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson: Yes I just saw that. Blame my DasKeyboard which has blank keys ;-)

Comment: "That conveniently allows us to neglect NaN cases." --> Setting aside  IEEE754, which a compliant C implementation does not need to follow (`__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` may be not defined), I find no C spec support that specifies the result when an operand to `<` is NAN.  In that case, `fun(NAN, x)` may return true.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Neither do I. Perhaps it's not clear that the second paragraph applies under IEEE754 but not necessarily under other schemes.

Comment: Is the 2nd paragraph "Let's assume ..." or "However, note ..."?  IAC, I read about overflow in this answer, but not much about NAN without IEEE754 compliance.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Well there's no harm in lobbing in a few more words. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Still, better to be explicit about what is possible w/o IEEE754 compliance too as OP did not oblige that.  UV anyways.